# Use one row of a different data frame at a time: R

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have two data frames. The first one contains types of businesses and the second contains location information:

```
employee <- c('A','B','C')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
workers <- c(500,200,300)

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, workers)
employ_name <- employ.data$employee
employ.data <- employ.data[, -(1)]
rownames(employ.data) <- employ_name

location <- c('NYC','Chicago','Miami')
salary <- c(66000, 55000, 40000)
workers <- c(5000,2050,1300)

location.data <- data.frame(location, salary, workers)
location_name <- location.data$location
location.data <- location.data[, -(1)]
rownames(location.data) <- location_name
```

I need to add the first row of employ.data to location.data (keeping the original indexes of both) and run a statistical test. Then, I need to remove the row I just added and add the second row to the location data frame and apply the same statistical test. I am trying to use a for loop but I am having trouble.

My data set is much larger than this - each data frame has 25 rows and I need to do this in an efficient way. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of statistical test do you need to do?

Comment: ANOVA Pairwise comparison

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
list_of_combined_dfs <- lapply(1:nrow(employ.data), function(ind) rbind(location.data, employ.data[ind,]))
list_of_combined_dfs

[[1]]
        salary workers
NYC      66000    5000
Chicago  55000    2050
Miami    40000    1300
A        21000     500

[[2]]
        salary workers
NYC      66000    5000
Chicago  55000    2050
Miami    40000    1300
B        23400     200

[[3]]
        salary workers
NYC      66000    5000
Chicago  55000    2050
Miami    40000    1300
C        26800     300
```

Here, `lapply` essentially loops over all rows of `employ.data`.

You can use `lapply` again to perform your statistical tests on each dataframe, of you build it into the function call of the first `lapply`. For instance, let's assume you want to run anova after a linear regression, then:

```
list_of_test_results <- lapply(1:nrow(employ.data), function(ind) {
  newdf <- rbind(location.data, employ.data[ind,])
  return(anova(lm(salary ~ workers, data = newdf)))})
list_of_test_results
[[1]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: salary
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
workers    1 910028056 910028056    7.88 0.1069
Residuals  2 230971944 115485972               

[[2]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: salary
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
workers    1 875636808 875636808  11.515 0.07695 .
Residuals  2 152083192  76041596                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

[[3]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: salary
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
workers    1 761233804 761233804  12.604  0.071 .
Residuals  2 120796196  60398098                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: If the OP wants ANOVA, maybe you could complete the answer with `lapply(list_of_test_results, anova)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have accepted the answer.